# use custom function in assetmanager

Tags: php, yii2

How use `Yii::$app->session['somename']` in yii2 assetmanager?

How make access some function in assetmanager?

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle{
public function getLang() {
  $currentLang = Yii::$app->session['lang'];
    if ($currentLang == 'fa' || $currentLang == 'ar') {
        return 'RTL';
    } else {
        return 'LTR';
    }
}
public $lang;

public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [
    'css/iconSprite.min.css',
     // how call getLang here
 ]
```

How call `getLang` in css part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
.. other functions

public function init() {
    $this->setupAssets();
    parent::init();
}

protected function setupAssets() {
    $lang = $this->getLang();
    $this->css[] = "css/myfile.$lang.css";
}
```